# How to merge and search duplicate values?

Tags: python

So I have a bunch of text files, I have to read them, count each word and output it in different file like this: (word)(file)(amount)

```
word1 file1 5
word1 file2 3
word2 file1 2
word2 file3 5
```

Then I need to sort them and merge all indentical words saving files and amounts, in something like that:

```
word1 file1:5 file2:3
word2 file1:2 file3:5
```

And make search function with two words to find filenames containing only both of searched words.

```
word1 in file1 counted 5
word2 in file1 counted 2
```

I do sorting but still need to do merging and searching :(

Comment: What do you mean by broken? And please extract the problem point from your code and post it. It is too difficult to read through the entire code and understand it.

Comment: And please don't use semicolons in Python code. For a moment, I thought this is not Python code :p

Comment: Maybe you could combine the data from your text files into a list and convert that to a set then back to a list (which would eliminate duplicates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you have done the first step (which seems to be the case), then you can do the following steps maybe like this:

```
#this is what you start with
words = [ ('word1', 'file1', 5),
    ('word1', 'file2', 3),
    ('word2', 'file1', 2),
    ('word2', 'file3', 5) ]

#grouped by words
simple = {}
for word, f, count in words:
    try: simple [word] [f] = count
    except: simple [word] = {f: count}

print (simple)

#find files which contain both w1 and w2
def findTwoWords (data, w1, w2):
    files1 = set (data [w1].keys () )
    files2 = set (data [w2].keys () )
    return files1 & files2

print ('"word1" and "word2" appear together in {}'.format (findTwoWords (simple, 'word1', 'word2') ) )
```